# How to display the copyright icon in UILabel text?

Tags: iphone, icons, special-characters, uilabel

Does any one know how to display the copyright icon in UILabel text? This is the icon with a circle around c. The html code for it is: `&copy;` or `&#169;`.

I tried the following code:

```
UILabel *contactInfo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-55,135,420,100)];
contactInfo.text = @"'&#169;):'2009 Nationwide ";
```

or

```
contactInfo.text = @"'&copy;'2009 Nationwide ";
```

or

```
contactInfo.text = @"&copy;2009 Nationwide ";
```

It just prints everything as text and no icon.

This would work in a webView but I need it as UILabel text.
Any help?

Comment: the html code is '& copy' without space
or
'& #169;'

Comment: Have you tried unicode? It's 169

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your source files are in UTF-8, what they should be, this should work just fine. Otherwise you should use .strings-files in combination with the NSLocalizedString() macro and put your text into UTF-16 files.

Works for me: `myUILabel.text = @"© by me";`

[image: © by me]
<sub>(source: [hillrippers.ch](http://www.hillrippers.ch/temp/Screen%20shot%202009-10-23%20at%2018.59.40.png))</sub>

*Edit:*
Now that I see that you've tried to insert the symbol as HTML entity - this does not work, just insert the symbol as it appears.

Answer (score 30):

In interface builder try <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> together.

If you don't have an <kbd>Option</kbd> key, try with <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to insert symbols without dealing with your source files' character encoding is to encode them as UTF-8 bytes using `\x` escapes.

According to [Fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a9/index.htm), the Copyright sign in UTF-8 bytes is 0xC2 0xA9.

So this works: `@"\xC2\xA9 Nationwide"`

That's how I do all of mine.

Answer (score 5):

Copy and paste the copyright symbol © directly into your source code.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a great idea to put non-ASCII strings through the compiler. The UTF-8 approach is thus better, if unreadable. You could use

```
NSLocalizedString(@"copyright", @"");
```

and then a .strings file with

```
copyright = "©2009";
```

would be a lot easier to generalize to other non-ASCII strings.

(BTW, it's option + g, not option + c.)

Answer (score 1):

From iOS6> we can use NSAttributedString concept. Please see the below code snippet. Please ignore if anyone already aware of this.

```
static NSString *html =
    @"<html>"
    "  <body>Here is copyright &copy; </i></body>"
    "</html>";

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 300, 200)];
    NSError *err = nil;
    label.attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithData: [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
     options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
     documentAttributes: nil
     error: &err];
    if(err)
        NSLog(@"Unable to parse label text: %@", err);
```